# sharp lc19sb27ut black bars on side with HDMI Cable (Used as PC monitor)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

[Link to manual for TV](http://files.sharpusa.com/Downloads/ForHome/HomeEntertainment/LCDTVs/Manuals/tel_man_LC19SB27UT_LC22SB27UT.pdf)

Okay. So Up until I had NVIDIA optimize DOOM 2016 for my GPU, my second monitor (the TV) was working fine. Then DOOM attempted to run the game on my second monitor, which has now screwed it up even more than it was when I first got it.

When I first got this thing, there were of course the black bars on the sides, but the top and bottom of the screen wasn't cut off. I forgot exactly how I did it, but I managed to get into some setting within the TV and remove the black bars, making the image perfect. My theory is that this option is in "PC Settings" in the Picture settings, but when I try and select it, it just goes past to the next option. This might be because it needs a VGA, but my new GPU doesn't have a VGA slot. Anyways, now the top and bottom are also cut off. I've tried changing the view mode, but stretch still cuts off the top and the only other mode, zoom, is basically useless. I finally found the remote hoping it would help, but it didn't.

I've tried factory resetting it, and have tried messing with the windows display settings, to no avail. I have the windows resolution setting on the native for the tv, and it hasn't helped. Here is an image of Discord being cut off (the top bar with the exit button is gone, and the settings icons at the bottom are cut off):
[Monitor 2 (TV)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqkNp.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with your TV, it's the resolution settings on your computer. Are you duplicating your monitors or do you have them extended?

Comment: @mael' extending. heres a screencap of my settings: https://imgur.com/a/tOL2A44 for some reason the main monitor is listed as "2"(1 is the not working one) maybe thats just because it's dvi and the tv is hdmi? though thats a different issue

Comment: I can't really see much from those particular settings, but based on what I _can_ see, it looks like you're not using the recommended resolution settings on the display you have selected (`1`). In that same vein, there's a chance that the recommended settings on one display are out of the operable range of the other. What resolutions are available for `1` in that drop-down? and what resolutions are available for `2`?

Comment: 2 is fine. the reccomended for 1 is 1280 x 720 but the native is 1366 x whatever (its in manual) and i have it set to the native. I still think its a tv thing due to the cutoff and stuff.it worked before

Comment: ah crap i made the resolution 1366 x 768 (the native) and now its cut off on the sides too this is epic. EDIT: could it be that the input resolution is 1920 x 1080? i mean it's always been that but i dont think it explains the cutoff. I've switched from stretch mode to zoom then back to stretch and its still cut off on the top and sides now also bottom. bruh.

Comment: I recommend putting the monitor's/TV's settings back on default - the black bars and cutting off is 100% an issue from the input - meaning you're goal is to fix the settings on your computer and not sabotage it with bad TV settings; that is backed up by the fact that DOOM auto-configuring your resolution settings is what hosed it in the first place - DOOM would only be accessing your computer's resolution options. That 1366 x 768 is the correct resolution for your TV according to the manual; configure both PC display resolutions and then try using the auto-adjust feature from your TV's menu